# NPM tries fetching a dependency that is never requested

Tags: node.js, npm

I typed `npm install` and got the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for duplexer2@^0.2.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'multipipe'
npm ERR! notarget
```

I look into the logs, and see that multipipe is a dependency of `emotion-server` which is a top-level dependency in my project:

```
50 silly saveTree ├─┬ emotion-server@9.2.12
50 silly saveTree │ └─┬ create-emotion-server@9.2.12
...
50 silly saveTree │   │     └── object-keys@0.4.0
50 silly saveTree │   ├── multipipe@1.0.2
```

Fair enough. Started to wonder why multipipe would specify a dependency that doesn't exist, but as it turns out `multipipe@1.0.2` never specified `duplexer2@^0.2.0`. Here's the package.json of `multipipe@1.0.2`:

```
{
  "name": "multipipe",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "pipe streams with centralized error handling",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": "juliangruber/multipipe",
  "dependencies": {
    "duplexer2": "^0.1.2",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^3.0.0",
    "through2": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "make test"
  }
}
```

As you can see, it requests `duplexer2` up to 0.1.2 (I believe that's the correct interpretation of ^) which does actually exist.

Funny thing, duplexer@0.2.0 (not duplexer**2**@0.2.0) is a dependency of react-dev-utils:

```
50 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ react-dev-utils@4.2.3
50 silly saveTree │ │ ├── detect-port-alt@1.1.3
...
50 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ gzip-size@3.0.0
50 silly saveTree │ │ │ └── duplexer@0.2.0
```

So maybe npm got a little confused, but I can't really prove it...I just want npm to fetch the correct dependencies.
(npm v6.4.1 on node v 11.5.0)

**Update**
I removed `emotion-server` from package.json, and did `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` and got a similar problem:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for websocket-extensions@>=0.2.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'websocket-driver'
```

The logs show `websocket-driver@0.7.0`:

```
59 silly saveTree │ │   ├─┬ faye-websocket@0.11.1
59 silly saveTree │ │   │ └─┬ websocket-driver@0.7.0
```

Ok, but the [package.json](https://github.com/faye/websocket-driver-node/blob/master/package.json) for websocket-driver@0.7.0 says '>=0.1.1' for websocket-extensions, it never said "websocket-extensions@>=0.2.0"

The @>= is something I've never seen before and doesn't make sense. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct understanding of `^`. A rule `^0.1.2` means that the major version should be `0` and the minor.patch version should be *at least* `1.2` but anything after that is fine, too. It's effectively `>= 0.1.2` with the restriction that the major version *has* to be `0`.

However, [as per semver rules](https://semver.org/#spec-item-4):

> 4. Major version zero (0.y.z) is for initial development. Anything may change at any time. The public API should not be considered stable.

If you want to see the full dependency tree for a package, have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-remote-ls to see what's actually to blame. Running that for multipipe there is no mention of a duplexer@0.2.0 anywhere so if you believe this to be a bug in npm, in addition to posting your question here, file an issue on the npm issue tracker at https://github.com/npm/npm/issues